# How can I read and work on a textual file starting from its path in Java?

Tags: java, file

I have the following task that have to be implemented in Java.

I have a String that represent the path of a **txt** file, something like this:

```
String fileFatturePa = "C:\\Users\\Andrea\\Desktop\\D150316.T1642\\myFile.txt";
```

This textual file contains some text (that represent XML but this is not important because I do not have to operate on it with something like XPath but I have to do simple substring operation).

So I need to read this textual file (starting from its path) and then I have to do some textual operation.

This file could be very big.

What is the best way to read it stargint from its path?

Comment: What have you done? Show some code, solve some problems. The Java API javadocs are there for your readng pleasure, and shoving "open file for reading" into a browser web search is easy.

Comment: what do you mean by working on a file? do you want to read from it or write to it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to read a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you reach a reputation of 4000 ... and then come here and ask questions like a complete newbie?

Comment: I will add that because of the nature of XML files, if you go down the path of treating this like a plain text file, and you want to make changes to it, you are going to have a bad day. Use one of the XML libraries out there to walk the elements and make your changes.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point is the official Java documentation by Oracle: [Basic I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Answer (score 1):

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileFatturePa));

        try
        {                           
            String line = null;         
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                  ***operations(specific to each line of the text file) ***
            }               
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }               

        finally
        {
            reader.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you create a new File: `File f = new File(path)`. For raed all the lines, you can use the class Fileutils from Apache Commons IO. And you will have something like: `List<String> allLines=Fileutils.readlines(f)`

Comment: "This file could be very big." Now, how to solve that pesky `OutOfMemoryError` without redesigning the whole file reader...

Comment: I found this article yesterday: http://www.baeldung.com/java-read-lines-large-file

Comment: Yes, and your example is **not** one of the "streaming" or "iterator" based approaches discussed therein. The example you give can make the heap grow unbounded as the file size grows.